# Genymotion virtual device not launching from windows 8.1 virtualbox

Tags: java, android, virtual-machine, virtualbox, genymotion

I download the virtualbox+genymotion installer and installed it. Then created a virtual device as in screenshot here: 
[image]

But when I launch it, I get this error:
[image]

`The kernel requires an x86-64 cpum but only detected an i686 CPU`

So how do I fix it?
I am on windows 8.1, 64bit processor.

**EDIT**

I have already enabled virtualization from BIOS, but no use. 
Hyper-V is also enabled from control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Intel VT-x/AMD-V from BIOS